# Hosting files, such as PDFs, alongside your code on Launchpad

Tags: programming, development, launchpad

I'm using Launchpad to host the code for my masters project and would like to host file that are ancillary to the project, such as documentation in PDF format, alongside the code. I've been looking around my project page but have been unable to find anything that looks like it will do this. Is there a 'file upload' mechanism built into Launchpad, or do I simply have to push them out as a branch of their own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just push them as you would any regular file. I don't know of any file hosting mechanism on Launchpad, but then, it's not likely to find such a thing on any other code hosting site either.

If you create a new branch though, you can push just about any file type there.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a *release* in your project, you can upload files from the release page.

I suppose you could create something like a "documentation" series with it's own releases, but if you're going to do that, you might as well just go the extra step and create a branch.